# Best way to divide CPU along all sql instances on 1 server

Tags: sql-server, cpu

I have a physical server with 40 CPU's (hyperthreaded) with 2 NUMA nodes. On this server I have 20 SQL Server instances installed and I need to make sure each instance has some dedicated CPU assigned into.

The problem is that sometimes one or more of the instances are using all of the CPUs and then about 4 or 5 instances are out of CPU resources and failing.

What is the best way to spread CPU among all of the instances so each instance has some at the minimum?

Comment: The best way would be to have ONE instance and use the resource governor to make sure no instance is hogging the machine.

Comment: Thanks, agree but unfortunately i can' modify anything right now and i need to do something with the current design.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure the processor affinity used by an instance of SQL Server by right clicking the instance and choosing [Properties -> Processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-properties-processors-page?view=sql-server-2017):

> Processor Affinity
>
> Assigns processors to specific threads to eliminating processor reloads and reduce thread migration across processors. For more information, see affinity mask Server Configuration Option.

This will enable you to assign specific processors per instance. Getting this right though requires constant attention and tuning so generally I don't advise it unless you really know what you are doing.

If you do decide to proceed, then I highly recommend reading about the [affinity mask Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/affinity-mask-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) before you attempt it and also you can read a quick [tutorial](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15264.configuring-sql-server-cpu-utilization.aspx) on TechNet and some basic guidelines can be found on [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319942/how-to-determine-proper-sql-server-configuration-settings).

Comment: Thank you, do you think using Resource Governor is the better solution in this case?

Comment: No because there is no workload management between SQL Server Instances and you would have to configure and manage it across each one you have. I think the affinity is probably your best way to go but you may have to tweak allocations until they are balanced correctly across your instances. Your other option is to configure the MAXDOP but this does not constrain SQL Server to specific CPU's it only constrains the amount that can be used for parallel queries and not everything is a parallel query.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: One more question please, let's say for 1 instance i decided to assign 4 cpu's , should i setup 2 for numa1 and 2 for numa2?

Comment: I would recommend keeping an instance on a single NUMA node if you can.

Comment: Thank you, and the last question. Do i need to leave any of the cpu's unassigned for the OS? Lets say CPU 0 for OS and CPU 1,2 and 3 for SQL.

Comment: You should be able to determine that through testing your configuration. If you only have SQL Server on the host then you may get away with it, but if you have a lot of other background processes external to SQL Server then it may be beneficial for you to do so.

Answer (score 2):

We have the same scenario, 12 cores with 6 SQL instances on the same machine.

What we did with allocation was to use Processor Affinity to make sure a single instance is only using 10 cores, and then spread it evenly as follows
Instance 1 is not using CPU0 and CPU1
Instance 2 is not using CPU2 and CPU3
Instance 3 is not using CPU4 and CPU5
..and so on

This prevents a single instance from bringing the whole server down, and it works like a charm